# Install coc.nvim on Raspberry Pi 4B on Pi OS

Tags: plugin-coc, plugin

I have successfully installed vim and two plugins on my raspberry pi 4b with Pi OS (linux). But when I installed coc.nvim vim gave an error (error code 1) and then showed erratic behaviour. Am I doing some obvious thing wrong?

Comment: I believe we will need more information about the error message and the erratic behavior to help you. It could also be that the problem is more relative to the coc plugin or the underlying language server. It would be interesting to know for which language you installed the server.

Comment: I was afraid you would ask this :), I will try (English is not my native language).

The errorcode was just a red line, saying it gave errorcode 1. 

After that, when entering I saw a screen full of code (?) I can’t explain, and I don’t know the language.

After that an empty screen, even tho I had opened a textfile.

The language I want to use is Rust.

Comment: I suppose you can get back these messages using the `:messages` command. It would be good if you could add them to the question ;-)

Comment: "Am I doing some obvious thing wrong?" Yes, you are asking your question here instead of CoC's official support channels.

Comment: Very friendly. But I see. And I stand corrected.